# What's wrong with my provided admin password for Oracle Apex instance administrator account?

Tags: oracle, password, oracle-apex

I have installed Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition on Oracle Linux 7.8.I am now trying to install [Apex 20.1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmig/downloading-installing-Oracle-AE.html) .

Got to the chapter "5.4.2.3 Running apxchpwd.sql" to set the instance administrator password. Executed the `@apxchpwd.sql` command, it asks me for user name, e-mail and password but then it gives an error as if the password does not have enough complexity, although the password I provide is literally `H29dN8%Ih^^IV$Y3$j4Mx`. Tried various other passwords, nothing seems to be acceptable.

What can be the problem?

Here is how I got to the error:

```
[oracle@oraclemachine apex]$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Aug 25 09:50:03 2020
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL>
SQL> @apxchpwd.sql
...set_appun.sql
================================================================================
This script can be used to change the password of an Application Express
instance administrator. If the user does not yet exist, a user record will be
created.
================================================================================
Enter the administrator's username [ADMIN] apexadmin
User "apexadmin" does not yet exist and will be created.
Enter apexadmin's email [apexadmin] a@b.c
Enter apexadmin's password []
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PASSWORD_COMPLEXITY_ERROR
* PASSWORD_ONE_ALPHA_ERR
* PASSWORD_ONE_PUNCTUATION_ERR
* PASSWORD_ONE_UPPER_ERR
* PASSWORD_ONE_LOWER_ERR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Password validation failed.
ORA-06512: at line 30
ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_FND_USER_INT", line 3744
ORA-06512: at line 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with that password. But just to be sure, check the variable if it really contains the password you entered (`print :PASSWORD`):

```
Thank you for installing Oracle Application Express 20.1.0.00.13

Oracle Application Express is installed in the APEX_200100 schema.

The structure of the link to the Application Express administration services is as follows:
http://host:port/pls/apex/apex_admin (Oracle HTTP Server with mod_plsql)
http://host:port/apex/apex_admin     (Oracle XML DB HTTP listener with the embedded PL/SQL gateway)
http://host:port/apex/apex_admin     (Oracle REST Data Services)

The structure of the link to the Application Express development interface is as follows:
http://host:port/pls/apex (Oracle HTTP Server with mod_plsql)
http://host:port/apex     (Oracle XML DB HTTP listener with the embedded PL/SQL gateway)
http://host:port/apex     (Oracle REST Data Services)

timing for: Phase 3 (Switch)
Elapsed: 00:00:06.97
timing for: Complete Installation
Elapsed: 00:05:01.54

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.





1 row selected.

...null1.sql
```

Then:

```
SYS> @apxchpwd.sql
...set_appun.sql
================================================================================
This script can be used to change the password of an Application Express
instance administrator. If the user does not yet exist, a user record will be
created.
================================================================================
Enter the administrator's username [ADMIN] apexadmin
User "apexadmin" does not yet exist and will be created.
Enter apexadmin's email [apexadmin] a@b.c
Enter apexadmin's password []
Created instance administrator APEXADMIN.

SYS> print :PASSWORD

PASSWORD
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
H29dN8%Ih^^IV$Y3$j4Mx

SYS>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I stumbled upon other problems preventing me to test your solution, but when I reinstalled Oracle Database and Apex, the `apxchpwd.sql` worked well - it did not complain about the password anymore.